# Xamarin: Give me some clarification with MVVM

Tags: mvvm, xamarin, viewmodel

I don't have a good understanding of MVVM and have read some articles on other pages.

Does the ViewModel do all the business logic and interact with data model which then send the data to the view for presentation.

On the View, will only have function that related directly UI.

This is my code I have code but not sure is it the correct way to do it

```
        private TestingViewModel Model
    {
        get
        {
            return BindingContext as TestingViewModel;
        }
    }

    public TestingPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = new TestingViewModel();
        Model.PropertyChanged += TestingPropertyChanged;

        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false); 

        MediaFactory.ClearAllCachedMedia(); 
        SetupTappedControl(); 
    }

    private void TestingPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName.Equals("ActivePage"))
        {
            if (Model.ActivePage != null)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                { 
                    var path = await MediaFactory.GetImagePathAsync(Model.ActivePage.DocumentId + "_" + Model.ActivePage.PageNumber);

                    CanvasView.Strokes = Model.ActivePage.Strokes;
                    CanvasView.LoadBitmapInMemory(path, Model.ActivePage.Width, Model.ActivePage.Height); 
                });
            }
        }
    }

    #region File Button Selected 

    public void TapFileOpen(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
          var pickFileTask = CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
          var data = pickFileTask.Result;
          Model.OpenDocument(data.FileName, data.DataArray);
        });

    }
```

> Question 1: Why I have to pass it to a BindingContext if I can just hold TestingViewModel object in the  Code-behind class of the View?

The line below :

```
                    CanvasView.Strokes = Model.ActivePage.Strokes;
                    CanvasView.LoadBitmapInMemory(path, Model.ActivePage.Width, Model.ActivePage.Height);
```

> Question 2 : The Strokes is a collection of stroke object. Do Strokes
>   also a ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

The Idea of the MVVM is to separate concern between creating Views and business logic.

the ViewModel will manage your business logic including implementation of `Properties` and `Commands` or `RelyCommands` that you will later on bind it into your views, So simple you will not have any code behind in your views on best case.

For better understanding for this pattern, I would suggest you to read this [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx) link that will illustrate to you how can you re-structure your code for better use and what are the benefits from using MVVM